# Perl appending regexp to search string pattern

Tags: regex, perl

I have a perl script that search can create user accounts for me on a email server. Now we have a number of old mailbox users that we want to delete from this server. The script needs to search for all accounts that starts with 'old****@example.com' and delete these accounts. 
We have declared:

```
my $accountNamePrefix='old';
```

and this should then list the accounts starting with the string 'old', but append then characters from [a-z] to complete the search for accounts to delete. The accounts are named for example:

```
oldajones@example.com
oldbsmith@example.com
oldcvanwyk@example.com, etc...
```

I need to search for the prefixed string 'old' and list these accounts for deletion. How can I do this with, i.e

```
my $account="$accountNamePrefix/[a-z]+/\@$Domain";
```

appending the regexp search to the decelared prefix.

Thank you.
Rudolf

Answer (score 0):

Everything is not clear to me so let's do some assumptions. First, you have a list of e-mails. I assume this list is a Perl array that can be described as:

```
my @email_list = ('foo@bar.com', 'oldbar@bar.com', 'oldfoo@bar.com', 'bar@bar.com');
```

Next, your input settings are the prefix and your domain name:

```
my $accountNamePrefix = 'old';
my $domain = 'bar.com';
```

Now, we need to build the regexp that match only old addresses:

```
/<old><anychars>@<domain>/
```

If you're not familiarized with regexps. Knows that you can simply replace the predefined settings by their variable name:

```
/$accountNamePrefix<anychars>@$domain/
```

And the  pattern can be written `\w+`. So we've got:

```
/$accountNamePrefix\w+@$domain/
```

Eventually if we put all together:

```
my @email_list = ('foo@bar.com', 'oldbar@bar.com', 'oldbar@bar.com', 'bar@bar.com');
my $accountNamePrefix = 'old';
my $domain = 'bar.com';

print join "\n", grep(/$accountNamePrefix\w+@$domain/, @email_list);
```

And the output is:

```
oldbar@bar.com
oldfoo@bar.com
```

Comment: I do not have the emails listed in an array as assumed. The email addresses are pulled from the imap email server. These emails addresses all start with 'old...@example.com' since they have been renamed. The regexp should be apended to the $accountNamePrefix to list the emails starting with old for deletion.

Comment: Where is declared your `$accountNamePrefix` variable ? In which script ?

Answer (score 0):

You can compose a regexp as follows

```
my $re = qr/$prefix.*\@$domain/;
```

or do so directly in a match

```
my $email =~ /$prefix.*\@$domain/;
```

There are some caveats to this, it assumes `$prefix`,`$domain` and `$email` are sanitised